# Rails Controller - Inherit a Custom Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have DRY'd up the controller code using inheritance.

```
class MastersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
    ...
  end

  ...
  ...
end

class ItemsController < MastersController
end
```

Now I have added a custom action to the MastersController

```
class MastersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
    ...
  end

  ...
  ...

  def clone
    ...
    ...
  end
end
```

I have added the routes for item

```
resources :items do
  get :clone
end
```

Now when I try to access myapp.dev/items/1/clone, I get the error

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /items/1/clone
The action 'clone' could not be found for ItemsController
```

[image: Screenshot]

If I add the 'clone' action in ItemsController the error goes away.

```
class ItemsController < MastersController
  def clone
    ...
    ...
  end
end
```

How do I abstract a custom action in Rails Controller?

Comment: Another question on around the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604996/rails-controller-inheritance-vs-concerns-and-mixins

Comment: Could this be an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998286/inheriting-and-routing-a-custom-action-from-applicationcontroller-in-rails (tadman's answer)

Comment: is `clone` below any private method? try to add the word `public` one line above `def clone`

Comment: It is not under private. From the screenshot, the error is raised from AbstractController. It is not reaching any of my code at all.

Comment: Have you tried adding the method to `ApplicationController` rather than `MastersController`?

Comment: I had this identical problem - I defined an action `clone` in `ApplicationController` and couldn't use it in `ItemsController`.  But if I defined `clone` directly in `ItemsController` it worked like you found.  When I renamed it from `clone` to `copy` it worked fine directly defined in the `ApplicationController`.  I never did find the reason - there is a Rails and Ruby method `clone` - don't know if that is connected.

Comment: @graeme-mclean It seems to be the answer. Please add it as a comment so that I can accept it. I have a few more actions such as "lock", "unlock" and all. I will now try my luck with these verbs/actions :-)

Comment: I've done this - hopefully someone with more knowledge can expand because I would like to know why too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use `clone` as an action which is inherited from a parent controller.  This is true of `ApplicationController` in addition to your `MastersController`.

Rename your action to `copy` and you will be able to define it in `MastersController` and route correctly to `ItemsController#copy`.

Please note, I cannot tell you why this is.  There is a Ruby method `clone` which is defined on the `Object` class.  I suspect this is the reason - maybe someone with more knowledge could explain.

Comment: There is a clone method for ActiveRecord. My code almost looks like this. def copy @master = @ master.clone render :new end

Comment: It's actually just documentation now; I think the method was deprecated in v2.3.8 and it just drops straight through to Ruby's `Object#clone` now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it like this

```
   def clone
     super
   end
```

in your child Controller